# Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I keep getting error "Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch"

> The Xamarin.iOS SDK version '14.20.0.24' that is installed on the Mac
> is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio. Would you like
> us to install Xamarin.iOS '14.20.0.25' for you? This will overwrite
> any other existing Xamarin.iOS installation on your Mac.

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.11.1

The problem is that I do understand the problem, but cannot download version 14.20.0.25 since it doesn't exist! The latest Xamarin.iOS (as of today 2021-08-17) is Xamarin.iOS 14.20.0.24

[Releases](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases)

Am I missing something? Where do I download 14.20.0.25? Normally, VS downloads this automatically, when it is a mismatch, but not this time.

Comment: Use the feedback tool in Visual Studio and report a bug. There is obviously a mistake here somewhere

Comment: Will do that, but before I do that, I want to know if others are having same issue as me?

Comment: Consider raising issue on github as well .

Comment: Could you please share a link to your bug report, if you made one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, there was a bug, Xamarin has managed to fix this in the lastest version.